# Set variable if it is unset in awk

Tags: awk, posix, conditional-operator

I want to set the variable `foo` to `bar` if `foo` was previously undefined. Currently I'm using

```
foo = foo ? foo : bar
```

But I have the feeling that there is a smarter way to do this in POSIX awk. For example in POSIX Shell I could write

```
${foo:-bar}
```

Comment: That also set `foo` to `bar` if `foo` is defined but 'not truthy' such as foo=0 or foo="". That is different than the POSIX shell example.

Comment: There is no such shorthand in awk. btw `foo = foo ? foo : bar` is incorrect. One can initialize it as `foo = ""` or `foo = 0`.

Comment: With GNU awk you have [typeof](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Type-Functions.html) but that is GNU only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robustly in any awk assuming `foo` is a scalar variable and cannot be an array:

```
foo = ( (foo == 0) && (foo == "") ? bar : foo )
```

An uninitialized scalar variable has the value zero-or-null as no "type" attribute (string or numeric) has been associated with it yet and so comparing a variable to both zero and null succeeds if it isn't set and fails otherwise.

Comment: I indeed meant, "Is there a shorthand form for foo = foo ? foo : bar, so i want to overwrite the value of foo with bar if foo is undefined, zero or an empty string. Since this does not seem to be the case and your question answers the question in the way I formulated it, I will accept the answer anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE #1 : for an even more short-hand formula, maybe like

```
("" < foo) < (foo == -foo) && foo = bar
```

Using a single `logical AND` (`&&`) in lieu of either a pair of `logical OR`s (`||`), the standard `if (...) { ... }` construct, or the `if-?-then-:-else` ternary operator that has a mandatory `else` section.

The tradeoff being 3 compares without short-circuit early exits have to be performed just to obtain the input value for the logical ANDs.

---

The least error-prone solution I could conjure up that avoids re-assigning `foo`'s value into itself every time is ::

```
    # gawk profile, created Wed Jun  7 04:56:39 2023

    # BEGIN rule(s)

    BEGIN {
    1   __ = __ == "NULL"         ?  _  : \
             __ == "EMPTY_STRING" ? ""  : \
             index(__, ".")       ? __  : \
             index(__, "n")       ? +__ : substr(__, 1, index(__, "s") - 1)
    }

    # Rule(s)

 5  {  print $0, "foo = (" (foo) ") , bar = (" (bar) ")"
    }
 5  NR == 1 { # 1
 1      foo = __
    }
 5  {
```

> `5`  **`"" < foo || foo < -foo || foo = bar`**

```
    }
 5  {   bar = 17 ^ (NR + NF)
    }
```

Test cases that take the form of `###n` or `###s` represent numbers that would be force type-casted to either numeric or string before test assigning into `foo`.

We see that only the truly `NULL` value of both `0` and `""` allows taking on `bar`'s value.

---

```
EMPTY_STRING
1             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  ()
2             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  (289)
3             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  (4913)
4             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  (83521)
5             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  (1419857)
NULL
1             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  ()
2             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  (289)
3             foo  =  (289)  ,  bar  =  (4913)
4             foo  =  (289)  ,  bar  =  (83521)
5             foo  =  (289)  ,  bar  =  (1419857)
-1n
1             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  ()
2             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (289)
3             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (4913)
4             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (83521)
5             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (1419857)
-1s
1             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  ()
2             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (289)
3             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (4913)
4             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (83521)
5             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (1419857)
0n
1             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  ()
2             foo  =  (0)    ,  bar  =  (289)
3             foo  =  (0)    ,  bar  =  (4913)
4             foo  =  (0)    ,  bar  =  (83521)
5             foo  =  (0)    ,  bar  =  (1419857)
0s
1             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  ()
2             foo  =  (0)    ,  bar  =  (289)
3             foo  =  (0)    ,  bar  =  (4913)
4             foo  =  (0)    ,  bar  =  (83521)
5             foo  =  (0)    ,  bar  =  (1419857)
1n
1             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  ()
2             foo  =  (1)    ,  bar  =  (289)
3             foo  =  (1)    ,  bar  =  (4913)
4             foo  =  (1)    ,  bar  =  (83521)
5             foo  =  (1)    ,  bar  =  (1419857)
1s
1             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  ()
2             foo  =  (1)    ,  bar  =  (289)
3             foo  =  (1)    ,  bar  =  (4913)
4             foo  =  (1)    ,  bar  =  (83521)
5             foo  =  (1)    ,  bar  =  (1419857)
-1n
1             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  ()
2             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (289)
3             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (4913)
4             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (83521)
5             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (1419857)
-1s
1             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  ()
2             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (289)
3             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (4913)
4             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (83521)
5             foo  =  (-1)   ,  bar  =  (1419857)
0.0
1             foo  =  ()     ,  bar  =  ()
2             foo  =  (0.0)  ,  bar  =  (289)
3             foo  =  (0.0)  ,  bar  =  (4913)
4             foo  =  (0.0)  ,  bar  =  (83521)
5             foo  =  (0.0)  ,  bar  =  (1419857)
```